# Problema con el sdk de flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

PS C:\Users\HERIBERTO> flutter --version
fatal: unterminated line in .git/packed-refs: ...
Failed to find the latest git commit date: VersionCheckError: Command exited with code 128: git -c
log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ad --date=iso
Standard out:
Standard error: fatal: unterminated line in .git/packed-refs: ...

Returning 1969-12-31 19:00:00.000 instead.
Flutter • channel unknown • unknown source
Framework • revision  () • 1969-12-31 19:00:00.000
Engine • revision e85ea0e79c
Tools • Dart 2.17.6 • DevTools 2.12.2
PS C:\Users\HERIBERTO>

Esto muestra al ejecutar el comando "flutter --version".

y si lo actulizo desde Android studio me sale esto:

fatal: unterminated line in .git/packed-refs: ...
Resolving dependencies...
The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.

Because crudseb depends on fluttertoast >=4.0.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.10.0, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer el problema es debido a que necesitas algunas dependencias:

> fatal: unterminated line in .git/packed-refs: ... Resolving
> dependencies... The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.
>
> Because crudseb depends on fluttertoast >=4.0.0 which requires Flutter
> SDK version >=1.10.0, version solving failed. pub finished with exit
> code 1 Process finished with exit code 1

Para una correcta instalación y configuración de Flutter usa ["Flutter Doctor"](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#run-flutter-doctor)

Desde una ventana de la consola donde se tiene el directorio Flutter, ejecuta el siguiente comando

```
flutter doctor
```

Ejemplo:

```
C:\usuario\flutter>flutter doctor
```

Esto realizará una búsqueda de dependencias que necesites para completar la correcta configuración.